# Transition in ListView to replace all elements

Tags: android, android-listview, android-transitions

I have a `ListView` that displays a list of states. Whenever the user selects a state, I will load a list of cities that are in this state. For this, I have a manager that, whenever an item is selected, will replace the underlying list that my custom `BaseAdapter` reads with the item's  children.

The problem is, this works fine, but the items are just replaced on the spot, I'd really want a nice transition for this, that is, the list of states moving to the left and being replaced by the list of cities coming from the other edge

Is there a class or method that could help me animate that? The only option I've thought is to keep two different `Listview` and fade the first one out while the other one fades in. Not the most elegant solution, I was wondering if this could be achieved somehow with only one `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with `ListView`, but I know you could use a `RecyclerView` and add animations in the adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method.

This method is called once for every visible item when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Edit:

Something like this:

**Some Class:**

```
RecyclerView recyclerv;
MyAdapter mAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
List<String> mDataset;

//instantiate recyclerview, adapter, layoutmanager, dataset. populate dataset.

recyclerv.setDataset(mDataset);
```

**MyAdapter.java:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> dataset;
    public MyAdapter(){}

    //extend ViewHolder class here
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Holder { ... }

    //implement onCreateViewHolder
    /*implement onBindViewHolder. 
     *animate your view here, but be sure to add an animation count
     else the items will keep getting animated everytime a new item appears */                              
   //implement getItemCount

    public void setDataset(List<String> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
        notifyDataSetChanged(); //this will trigger onBindViewHolder for every visible item
    }
}
```